# Selected segment of a segment controller should change when swiping a page view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I am designing a segment control in which I have I have implemented a page view controller to swipe in between views. And also I have implemented segment action functionality to switch between views when user touches any particular segment.

But the problem I am facing now is whenever I select a particular segment by clicking on the segment the selected segment changes but whenever I am swiping in between views I am unable to change selected index.

So can't I get every time the index of the view that loads ? Or any suggestion to my problem .

I have implemented the following functions .

```
 func viewControllerAtIndex(index : Int) -> UIViewController/
    {

    }
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {

    }


    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {


    }

    @IBAction func sendsegmentcontrollerIndex(sender: AnyObject)

    {

  //codes for changing the present view controller on segment selection

    }
```

So what I must to do now in order to get my expected result?
I even tried to add swipe gesture to my page view controller but in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
        didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
        previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
        transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
    {
        let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0] as! ContentViewController
        let index = pageContentViewController.pageIndex
        print(index)
        seg.selectedSegmentIndex = index



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override this delegate: `pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)`. Maybe you can implement like this:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if pageViewController.viewControllers?.first?.isKindOfClass([yourClass]) {
        //self.changeIndex()
    }
}
```

In this delegate you will detect what is page moved. And you will set your segment to index match with this `viewcontroller`.

Comment: func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
        didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
        previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
        transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
    {
        let pageContentViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers![0] as! ContentViewController
        let index = pageContentViewController.pageIndex
        print(index)
        seg.selectedSegmentIndex = index
        
        
        
    }

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: Please check the answer I have given and can you please explain me the first line of code in that function?

Comment: It just code to check what is view currently show on  ` pageviewcontroller`. Depend on it you can know what is selected index.

Comment: Ya got that but how is the present page stored in pageViewController.viewControllers![0] ?

Comment: It is a property of `UIPageViewController`. It is the Apple implement this class. You can reference to document of Apple for get more detail https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPageViewController/viewControllers

Comment: It is just written that it "The view controllers displayed by the page view controller." But what is there to do with 0 index ? If present view controller has zero index. What is the index number for previous view controller? Please help me to be clear. Thanks for your response

Comment: Check array `previousViewControllers: [UIViewController]` it will store what is controller scroll.